# jQuery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier but my code looks good! (I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

If you look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/k2ku2/) you'll see that I get this error on line 265 (when you inspect element).

I've split the error line into multiple parts so you can see exactly where the error occurs.

Why might it be happening?

Comment: Why don't you just show us the line of code where the error is occurring?

Comment: show the error here wit the line number

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to close your `document.ready` just before that line.

```
document.ready(function(){

...


}  <-- missing )

other stuff
```